# Woocommerce page with different number of columns

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, woocommerce

My Woocommerce website shows 3 columns of products in every loop page.

I'm making some custom landing page where i want to show the loop of products in 4 column instead of 3.

I tryed with this code inside function.php:

```
add_filter('loop_shop_columns', 'loop_columns');
if (!function_exists('loop_columns')); {
function loop_columns() {
    if (is_page(91040)){
        return 4; 
    }else{
        return 3; 
    }
}
}
```

without success.

Is there a way to have in a single or specific page a different number of column compared to the others?

Comment: are you using woothemes theme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue. The problem was in the is_page function. It can't get the correct ID so i have found a workaround:

```
function loop_columns() {
   global $woocommerce;
   $url = explode('?', 'http://'.$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
   $ID = url_to_postid($url[0]);
   if ($ID == 91040){
       return 4; 
   }else{
       return 3; 
   }
}
add_filter('loop_shop_columns', 'loop_columns', 999);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using woothemes theme or any other theme which is already utlisiing the loop_columns filter, then you need to override that with two things, by removing the if !function exit condition, and also adding pririty to filter high enough like 999 so it is applied at the last:

e.g.

```
// Override theme default specification for product # per row
function loop_columns() {
   return 5; // 5 products per row
 }
add_filter('loop_shop_columns', 'loop_columns', 999);
```

You may adjust the function as per you needs like adding page template conditional as you have in your original code.

Source:
https://docs.woothemes.com/document/change-number-of-products-per-row/  Second headline

Comment: Hi @Mohsin, thanks for your reply. i have just edited my code in:

`function loop_columns() {
 if (is_page(91040)){
  return 4; 
 }else{
  return 3; 
 }
}
add_filter('loop_shop_columns', 'loop_columns', 999);`

but it doesn't work.

It's like it can't recognize the page ID, infact if i try only `return 5;` it works.

Comment: I see, you are calling this outside the loop. You need to add this global $post; before your is_page line

Comment: @ManuelRagazzini if my answer was any assistance, upvote and choose answer will be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score -2):

I spent a lot of brain matter trying to control the number of columns in a custom template. I am new to WooCommerce and Wordpress so am on a learngin curve. However, I started off with:

```
<ul class="products">
    <?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product',
        'posts_per_page' => 12
        );
    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
    if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
            wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
        endwhile;
    } else {
        echo __( 'No products found' );
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
</ul><!--/.products-->
```

When applied as a template it gave me a custom loop that I could fiddle with. However, from there I wanted 5 columns and just could not figure it out. I tried all the things Google could throw up such as filers and such. However, I finally discovered that the above snippet starts off with the

```
<ul class="products">
```

tag. All I did was dd the appropriate colum class:

```
<ul class="products columns-5">
```

This might require additional thinking regarding the responsive aspects, but it crosses the immediate barrier of controlling columns with that snippet. However, it does actually seem to respond quite well.